# systemctl reload nginx very slow and this is causing problems with certbot renewal

Tags: nginx, certbot

I've been running an nginx webserver with approximately 60 websites, and I've noticed that running the following commands is very slow:

- `systemctl reload nginx` takes around 20 seconds.
- `systemctl restart nginx` takes 30+ seconds.

I've also encountered issues when trying to issue or renew SSL certificates using certbot. It fails, citing that it cannot find the challenge file. After troubleshooting this secondary issue, I found that running the certbot command with these flags - `--debug-challenges -v` - causes a pause before trying to issue the certificates. If I wait 25 seconds and then continue the process, it works without error. I've confirmed that it takes 25 seconds for the challenge files to become accessible via the provided URLs. I believe that challenge files are being loaded into the nginx config but are not immediately available via the URL because nginx takes so long to reload the configs.

The biggest issue this is causing is that the automatic certbot renewals fail, so I'm currently having to run renewals manually.

In short, I need help troubleshooting this issue.

Edit - I've done some troubleshooting. I removed all symbolic links from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and then added them back one by one. I noticed that each site added (roughly) 0.1 seconds to the time it takes nginx to parse the sites.

I checked this with the following command:
`time nginx -t`

By the time I added all my sites - around 60 sites - the time it takes for the above command to run is around 7 seconds.

I also tried adding one site only and making the site file as basic as possible, and it still took around the same time to run `nginx -t`. So I don't think it's the config files themselves.

Do you have any other ideas for troubleshooting? Is it possible that it relates to IPv6? I don't think I have an IPv6 address for my server, so I don't know if that could be causing an issue.

Comment: It is possible that the problem is the long processing of DNS requests. If you change the DNS server (`/etc/resolv.conf`) to any public server, is the problem repeated?

Comment: I tried adding a public server in here then I confirmed the public server was being used to serve queries by running nslookup google.com. then I reloaded nginx but still same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I've organized my comments into an answer to make it easier to search in the future.

- [comment1513066_1156776](https://serverfault.com/questions/1156748/systemctl-reload-nginx-very-slow-and-this-is-causing-problems-with-certbot-renew/1156776#comment1513066_1156776)
- [comment1513067_1156776](https://serverfault.com/questions/1156748/systemctl-reload-nginx-very-slow-and-this-is-causing-problems-with-certbot-renew/1156776#comment1513067_1156776)

---

### The core issue of the question

> the biggest issue this is causing is that the automatic certbot renewals fail so I am currently having to run renewals manually.

### My answer

You can make certbot to wait for nginx's reloading with these ways.

#### with the command-line option

[Certbot > User Guide > Certbot command-line options](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#certbot-command-line-options)

```
  --nginx-sleep-seconds NGINX_SLEEP_SECONDS
                        Number of seconds to wait for nginx configuration
                        changes to apply when reloading. (default: 1)
```

#### with the configuration file

[Certbot > User Guide > Configuration file](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#configuration-file)

> Certbot accepts a global configuration file that applies its options to all invocations of Certbot.

> By default no cli.ini file is created (though it may exist already if you installed Certbot via a package manager, for instance).

From [an issue in certbot's repo in GitHub](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/8735#issuecomment-807520469)

> You can also put:
>
> ```
> nginx-sleep-seconds = 30
> ```
>
> into `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini`, to make it global.

---

My original post is below:

---

In the example unit file below, `nginx -s reload` is set as `ExecReload`.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/

> ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload

The option seems to lead graceful shutdown.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html

> reload — reload configuration, start the new worker process with a new configuration, gracefully shut down old worker processes.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/

> The more interesting option however, is being able to change the NGINX configuration on the fly

If the option or like it is set in your emvironment, is it possible that this behavior is causing the delay?

Comment: In the config file mentioned in that article, the exec reload line is like this - ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload

Comment: Thank you for sharing it. It seems to be better to use the option to avoid unintended downtime of nginx. By the way, how about to make certbot to wait for nginx's reloading. Could you try `—nginx-sleep-seconds`?

Comment: I read this issue. I hope it would help you. https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/8735

Comment: The fix noted in the link you referenced (https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/8735) has worked! to confirm, I edited this file (Which was empty beforehand) - /etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini - and added the following line - nginx-sleep-seconds = 30 I then tested renewing one certificate like this - certbot -v renew --cert-name domain.com and it renewed succesfully so I beleive the problem is solved thank you very much for your help

Comment: Congratulations! I'm glad to hear that.